# Eureka Server giving Whitelabel Error Page error in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am trying to run Eureka Server to get the Eureka System Status page.

I am getting Whitelabel Error Page error when I run my project.

Here is my `applications.yml` file

```
# This default profile is used when running a single instance completely standalone:
spring:
profiles: default
server:
  port: 9000  
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: my-eureka-server.com
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

I want to be able to view my Eureka Status page instead of the error.

NOTE: Source of tutorial is this [Eureka Server](https://o7planning.org/en/11733/understanding-spring-cloud-eureka-server-with-example)

Comment: hostname should be `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this in your application.yml:

```java
spring:
  freemarker:
    template-loader-path: classpath:/templates/
    prefer-file-system-access: false
```

see here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/2.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi_spring-cloud-eureka-server.html#netflix-eureka-server-starter